# Пришедшая по почте картинка не открывается

Tags: php

Отправляю картинку на почту средствами PHP, пришедшая картинка не открывается:

```
function send_mail($mail_to, $thema, $html, $path)
{
if ($path) {
    $fp = fopen($path, "rb");
    if (!$fp) {
        print "Cannot open file";
        exit();
    }
    $file = fread($fp, filesize($path));
    fclose($fp);
}
$name     = "foto.jpg"; // в этой переменной надо сформировать имя файла (без всякого пути)  
$EOL      = "\r\n"; // ограничитель строк, некоторые почтовые сервера требуют \n - подобрать опытным путём
$boundary = "--" . md5(uniqid(time())); // любая строка, которой не будет ниже в потоке данных.  
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0;$EOL";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"$EOL";
$headers .= "From: zakaz@energy-trucks.ru\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: zakaz@energy-trucks.ru\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";

$multipart = "--$boundary$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8$EOL";
$multipart .= $EOL; // раздел между заголовками и телом html-части 
$multipart .= $html;

$multipart .= "$EOL--$boundary$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$name\"$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"$EOL";
$multipart .= $EOL; // раздел между заголовками и телом прикрепленного файла 
$multipart .= $file;

$multipart .= "$EOL--$boundary--$EOL";

if (!mail($mail_to, $thema, $multipart, $headers)) {
    //// если письмо не отправлено
    echo "Повторите пожалуйста отправку сообщения, не сработало..";
}
}
```

Comment: [пример][1]


  [1]: http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/php_mail_attach.txt.html

Answer (score 1):

Не путайте MIME'ы, это плохая практика. Ваш файлик - это image/jpg. Еще нужно саму картинку получить, base64 кодировать, сплитить.

Вот [работающий пример](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html).
А вообще, советую [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).